# Simple Client Side Validations in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Basically, I have 10 validations on a form in my Rails app. If there are errors, the page refreshes & shows the errors in a box.

**How can I show the error box without refreshing?** I would like the box to display after clicking submit.

I saw a railscasts episode on client side validations using a gem but it seemed a bit too much & complicated for what I'm going after, plus I couldn't get it working. Looking through some of SO's similar questions, I know I'll have to use jquery/java but I'm still sort of lost. Could someone point me in the right direction

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider either rolling your own client-side solution, or using a Javascript/jQuery library.

Personally, I've had a lot of luck with [jQuery.validationEngine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine). It enables configurable and extensible form validations which work well out-of-the-box:

[image]

And while I haven't tried it myself, [jquery-validation](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) seem to be another popular client side validation library.

There are surely many other libraries out there for doing what you're looking to accomplish, but I'm fairly confident there's a good reason why these two are among the most popular solution. Additionally, both are well-documented and lay out concise instructions for simple implementations on their respective GitHub pages.

Comment: Any simpler ones? Sort of like a simple flash error message box listing all the errors  without refreshing the page?

Comment: Flash errors, by definition, require the business logic performed within a controller – so a page load is necessary. jQuery.validationEngine is pretty simple to implement... have you given it a try?

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for but it will come in handy. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can Check Here.. Very good documentation..

https://sunilsharma3639.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/jquery-ketchup-plugin-for-client-side-form-validation/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/jbmyid/rails_jq_validations

This is too simple to use.